# If you shove/push an object and it decelerates, does it lose its applied force over time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

When you initially push the object across a surface and the acceleration is zero, it has a specific applied force, right? So as the object decelerates from friction, does the applied force decrease over time?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise if you don't stop pushing the object at a constant force, why would it even decelerate?

Comment: It's not entirely clear (at least to me) what you're asking. In your first question,  What is "it"? What kind of surface are you talking about? What do you mean by the "applied force"? applied by what? Is it the force that is pushing the object or the kinetic friction force opposing the motion of the object? The answer to your second question depends on whether the force is the one pushing the object or the kinetic friction force. Please clarify or I will vote to close.

Comment: I was confused about applied forces (assuming by a person pushing, let's say a box, forward across a surface with some friction opposing its motion), not understanding that after you push the box it no longer has that applied force. I had thought that it continued moving because it had a force (applied force by the person) in the direction of its motion, and that applied force decreased over time due to the opposing friction, causing the box to come to a stop. So I asked if this was true and found out it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: No,

If we shove or push an object with an instantaneous force it gains impulse, momentum & the kinetic energy. Over the time, the objects loses gained kinetic energy or velocity due to dissipative effects (like friction, drag force, viscous force, collision etc.) but not force which is applied by external agent.

The applied force remains in existence until removed by external agent it does not spontaneously lose applied force. Force is applied instantly or over a period of time depending on external agent.

Answer (score 0):

If you push an object you are applying a force.  If that is the only force acting on the object you will cause the object to gain (or lose) velocity, kinetic energy, and momentum, but it does not gain a force.  If your moving object interacts with another object (as in a collision or with friction) then it can exert a force on the other object, but not necessarily the same as the force that you applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember Newton's first law of motion. Every object would preserve it's motion or state of rest unless a force acts on it. When you shove any object, it gains velocity/momentum which it would like to preserve by Newton's first law. However, due to friction and air drag, the velocity of the object would certainly decrease until it finally stops by Newton's second law. If somehow we could find a way to effectively reduce friction, the object would continue moving with the same speed forever and ever. Even the slightest push would keep it moving non stop. This is the principle behind the air track glider used for physics demonstrations. You can think of it this way: the object is not going to stop if there is nothing stopping it. This is the idea behind Newton's first law of motion.